# Lightspark error in Firefox: "appears to be damaged"

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, firefox, flash

[Lightspark](https://lightspark.github.io/) doesn't work in Firefox, because the file I downloaded (newest version) "appears to be damaged."

In the firefox-menu, you should be able to install it from a file. Why does it "appear to be damaged" and what can I do to "fix" it?

Are there any other methods to make Firefox recognize Lightspark (which I already have installed via terminal)?

Answer (score 0):

I''ll answer this for the sake of completeness.

Installing [Lightspark](http://lightspark.github.com/) should probably just be done from the Ubuntu Software Center or from Synaptic.

If you already had gnash or Adobe Flash installed, you might want to disable them from the Firefox Add-ons->Plugins menu so the right one (Lightspark) is used.

Personally, Lightspark crashed on the first video I tried to see, but you might get better results.